# Regex pattern to match APK filename from a log file

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a problem to build a regex pattern to suit all the modifications in my log file. It is a log file full of extracted Android APK packages. It looks like this:

```
"\\fileserver\folder1\20151215\15\com.some.package1_658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c:\assets\fonts\somefile-LightIt.otf" is OK
"\\fileserver\folder1\APK_white\20151215\15\com.some.package2_658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c" is OK
"\\fileserver\folder1\20151215\15\com.some.package3.android_4538d62efe8b312a5adc4ed6aee14d2c37b7da48:\assets\SD\emotions\873.zip:\873\873.png" is OK
"\\fileserver\folder1\20151215\15\com.some.package4.android_4538d6abfe8b312a5adc4ed6aee14d2c37b7da48:\assets\SD\emotions\873.zip:\873\873.sam" is OK
"\\fileserver\folder1\20151215\15\658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c:\assets\fonts\somefile-LightIt.otf" is OK
```

All I need is to get the name of the APK packages. It means I need to get the following from the mentioned example:

```
com.some.package1_658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c
com.some.package2_658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c
com.some.package3.android_4538d62efe8b312a5adc4ed6aee14d2c37b7da48
com.some.package4.android_4538d6abfe8b312a5adc4ed6aee14d2c37b7da48
658d67d60f573a2874c0163bdd3686eb9b15753c
```

I created this "brutal" regex:

```
((?!.+:\\.*)(?:".+\\(.+)"\s.*))|((?=.+:\\.*)(?:".+\\(.{2,}):\\.*"))
```

It works ok until APK package which includes another archive is found (last 2 rows from my example). It means more ":\" on the same line.

I'm lost. Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Why use regex? It looks like a property like `Filename` from a `Path` object can do this out of the box (depending on your language).

Comment: I need to parse a log file in C#. I do not have these files physically

Comment: When selecting between `"` characters It is still a valid path.

Comment: `Path.GetFileName(@"\\fileserver\folder1\20151215\15\com.some.package3.android_4538d62efe8b312a5adc4ed6aee14d2c37b7da48:\assets\SD\emotions\873.zip:\873\873.png");` Returns 873.png. Same as my wrong regex

Comment: Fair point. It gets the filename and not the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the log line by line and get the APK filename using this expression below. It will get everything from the last `\` character until the first `:` character.

```
[^\\]*?(?=:+)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to be a regex, you could come up with:

```
(com[^:\\\n\r"]+)
# look for com literally
# match everything that is not a colon, backslash, double quote or linebreak
# capture everything into a group
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bP6cS5/2). Otherwise, follow @Maurice's advice.

Comment: unfortunately APK filename can begin with any character. It is not "com" only

Comment: So then, what is the business logic (in words) for us to know what is the APK filename? Or else just use backtracking from the `:` to the first found `\\` character.

Comment: filename can include anything except reserved characters (NTFS). Backtracking as you mentioned won't work, because there could be a lot of ":" and backslashes. Generally I need everything between first appearence of ":\" and last backslash before this first ":\"

Comment: @DavidRohlik: Please include some more expected input strings then.

Comment: @MauriceStam: This matches `873.zip` as well.

Comment: @MauriceStam: Thanks Maurice. It seems that your last regex works perfectly